# Having trouble finding the sum of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

"A lottery proposes the following payout scheme: in year 1 the winner receives $1000. In every
subsequent year the winner receives triple the amount from the previous year divided by the year
number."

**If the winner lives indefinitely would he/she receive a finite or infinite amount of money
under this payout scheme?**

I'm trying to find the sum of the series. I know it's not infinite and I already tried the notation $$\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{1000(3^{n-1})}{n}$$

however this doesn't work past n=2. Can anyone lead me in the right direction to finding the sum of this series? Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't your index be $n=1$, not $i=1$?

Comment: Oops, fixed that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

$x_1 = 1000$

$x_2 = 3*x_1 /2$

$x_3 = 3^2 * x_1 /6$

$x_4 = 3^3 * x_1 /24$

so we can claim that $x_n = 3^{n-1}/n! * x_1$ and we can prove it by induction.

Since n! grows much faster than $3^{n-1}$, the coefficient $3^{n-1}/n! $for $x_1$ will vanish as n gets bigger.

so the sum will be a finite amount of money under this payout scheme.

Comment: You did fine until the last two sentences. // For the next to last sentence it should be $x_n$ not $x_1$. // The last sentence is just wrong. The series does converge even though there are an infinite number of terms. The value will be $63618.46

Comment: Can you explain how you got the sum?

Answer (score 1):

The correct formula is

$$\frac{1000}3\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{3^k}{k!}=\frac{1000}3\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{3^k}{k!}-1\right)=\frac{1000}3(e^3-1),$$

by a well-known result in calculus ($e$ is the Euler constant).

---

By the Binomial formula,

$$\left(1+\frac3n\right)^n=1+n\frac3n+\frac{n(n-1)}2\frac{3^2}{n^2}++\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}\frac{3^3}{n^3}\cdots$$

As $n$ grows to infinity, the factors with $n$ simplify each other and what remains is the sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{3^k}{k!}.$$

On another hand, with $3m=n$

$$\left(1+\frac3n\right)^n=\left(1+\frac1m\right)^{3m}=\left(\left(1+\frac1m\right)^m\right)^3=e^3,$$

where

$$e=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{k!}$$ is a classical mathematical constant.

---

You can show that the series converges because for $k>3$, $\dfrac{3^k}{k!}<\dfrac{3^k}{3!4^{k-3}}$ (the denominators are $1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdots$ and $1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4\cdots$), and the series is bounded above by a converging geometric series.

Comment: Your initial sum has that $a_1=3000$.

Comment: @Bonnaduck That's right, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your summation is set up wrong. We have

$a_1=1000 \\
a_2=\frac{3a_1}{2} \\
a_3=\frac{3a_2}{3}=\frac{3^2 a_1}{3!}\\
...\\
a_n=\frac{3^{n-1}a_1}{n!}.$

So, we can just solve the summation

$$\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n
&=1000\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^{n-1}}{n!}
\\&=\frac{1000}{3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^{n}}{n!}
\\&=\frac{1000}{3}\left(\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3^n}{n!}\right)-1\right)
\\&=\frac{1000}{3}(e^3-1).\end{align*}$$